# Camera movement around the model

Tags: java, opengl, camera

I want to make my camera move behind the model when it rotates, just like in a Third Person Perspective game - to have it "look" always on the back of the model. Im provided with a framework so the syntax may be bit different than normal opengl. I use the standard camera

`Mat4 mv = MatrixMath.lookAt(this.eyeX,this.eyeY,this.eyeZ,this.at,this.up);`

and to rotate the camera i tried

`this.mouseRotation += 20.0f;

            this.eyeX = (float) Math.sin(this.mouseRotation / 180.0f * 3.14f) * 2.0f;
            this.eyeZ = (float) Math.cos(this.mouseRotation / 180.0f * 3.14f) * 2.0f;`

mouseRotation is the angle which the model is located so obviously the camera should be also move to a position located 20 degrees further on the "circle". But instead of this the object rotates around itself, and the camera makes a circular movement but not around the model, but next to it, still looking at the same point.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, I believe the short answer is to add `this.at` (which should be the position of your object) into your `this.eye` so that that the eye is positioned relative to the object.

In more detail, say your object's position is at `this.at`, and you want the camera to follow the object at some distance, say 'd' "behind" the object.  If you have a unit vector (i.e., one's whose length is 1.0) pointing out of the front of the object, then the `this.at - d` should be the position of the camera (i.e., `this.eye`).  In order to get the camera to rotate around the object, first apply a rotation to 'd' (in the example above, you appear to be rotating around the 'Y' axis [since you're only modifying eyeX and eyeZ]), so that

```
this.eye = this.at - rotation(Y) * d;
```